# Python yfinance - how remove the time zone?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, yfinance

I wrote this small code. How can I remove the "hours" timing in the excel ? See the screenshot below.

```
import os
import yfinance
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

a=yfinance.download('CS.PA', interval='1mo')
print(a)

save_name="C:\\Users\\Lex02\\Desktop\\Python2\\Bourse essai_3.xlsx"
a.to_excel(save_name)

a_excel=load_workbook(filename=save_name)
ws=a_excel.active

os.system('pause')
```

[image]

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Format your index:

```
a = yfinance.download('CS.PA', interval='1mo')  
a.index = a.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') # Enter whatever format here
```